# Hibernate converts unqualified class name to qualified and gives syntax error

Tags: hibernate, escaping, hql, keyword

I am writing following HQL query.

```
select a.col1, a.col2 from MyEntity a
```

But Hibernate creates this query as

```
select a.col1, a.col2 from in.xxx.yyy.zzz.MyEntity a
```

Here in.xxx.yyy.zzz is the package name of the MyEntity, which is mentioned in the hbm.xml file. Now when hibernate executes this query it gives following error.

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting OPEN, found '.' near line 1, column 264
```

I think it is considering the 'in..' in the package name as IN key word and expecting some value in it.

Question is why hibernate is using fully qualified path name for this entity while I am using simple name in HQL ?

Can we escape entity name it is having special keywords ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

I have to add the entity-name attribute in my hbm.xml having value as only unqualified class name as following.

```
<class name="in.xxx.yyy.zzz.MyEntity" entity-name="MyEntity" 
table="MY_TABLE">
```

But the pain is I have to add this attribute to all the entity hbm files which are mapped with this entity.

But it is working.

Thanks Joe Taras for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Put alias a after entity name because you have used a.col1, a.col2.

The query:

```
select a.col1, a.col2 from MyEntity a
```

Hibernate convert all namespace because you can define more classes with the same name in different package, so if Hibernate builds all path there's no ambiguity

Comment: Ok. I have updated the query. But now my question is if my package name starts with 'in...' then hibernate treats it as in keyword. How can I avoid this ?

Comment: @vrajesh: I think no problem because package is always followed by full stop (i.e. in.MyClass if you have first level package or in.subPackage1....MyClass for other levels). You have problem if you use in with space after and you don't refer to reserved keyword.

Comment: No that is what the error is telling, that it is expecting OPEN but found '.' near in. And to change the package name is not possible due to contractual and legal reasons.